# usage of "the" in "the English language"

Tags: definite-article

> 1. I am interested in **the** English language.
> 2. I  am interested in English language.

I want to know whether I need to put the definite article "the" before the word "language".

Comment: Depending on the context, _language_ is a count noun or a mass noun. It's a mass noun here: _"The students learned how children acquire language."_ You are referring to a specific language, so it's a countable noun. There are many languages to "count"! The definite article is correct here: **"I am interested in _the_ English language."**

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interested+in+English+language%2Cinterested+in+the+English+language&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinterested%20in%20English%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinterested%20in%20the%20English%20language%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

It's more common and grammatically correct to use "the" in front of English language.  However, if you want to avoid the indefinite article, it will be better to use English on its own as follows:

I am interested in English.